# Executing a remote .sh file from windows

Tags: linux, shell, batch-file

Im running a batch script in windows which will

- Perform some compilation and make a **zip file**.
- **Upload** this **zip file** to a **linux** box via **scp**.

After that I need to do some other jobs on the **uploaded zip file in linux**.

So is there any way to make a single script file to do all these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can use the various PuTTY utilities:

- `plink` allows you to pipe commands around to SSH servers, and invoke commands (akin to "ssh" on Linux)
- `pscp` allows for remote file copying using SCP or SFTP

http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

Comment: Thnx it worked just smoothly.
`plink user_name@my.host.com cd /home/user/Documents;./test.sh`